# Android - Video freezes in MediaPlayer after a while, no error is thrown

Tags: android, audio, video, android-mediaplayer

To simplify things, I have an app that is given with two url's, one for video file and one for audio file, and plays them using two MediaPlayers, one for each file.

My issue is that the video freezes after 1-3 seconds (changes every time) while the audio continues normally.
I don't get any errors or exceptions from that MediaPlayer, I even tried to take off the audio mediaplayer and leave only the video (as I though it's racing issues) but it still had the same behavior.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
    audioPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); // both media players declared outside
    audioPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    audioPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    audioPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    audioPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);

    videoPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    videoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    videoPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    videoPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    videoPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);

    try {
        audioPlayer.setDataSource(audioPath);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "audioPlayer.setDataSource(" + audioPath + ")");
        videoPlayer.setDataSource(videoPath);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "videoPlayer.setDataSource(" + videoPath + ")");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "setDataSource() - " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    try {
        audioPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float volume = Float.valueOf(options.getString("volume"));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "setVolume: " + volume);
        audioPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "setVolume() - " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        try {
            int scalingMode = options.getInt("scalingMode");
            switch (scalingMode) {
            case MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING:
                videoPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "setVideoScalingMode VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING");
                break;
            default:
                videoPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "setVideoScalingMode VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "setVideoScalingMode() - " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    final SurfaceHolder mHolder = videoView.getHolder(); //videoview is another view in the display, but it does nothing
    mHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    mHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Surface Created");

            videoPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            try {
                videoPlayer.prepareAsync();
                audioPlayer.prepareAsync();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "prepare()");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() - " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Surface Destroyed");

            try {
                audioPlayer.release();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                // already released
            }
            try {
                videoPlayer.release();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                // already released
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Surface Changed");
        }
    });

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "MediaPlayer prepared");

    if (mp.equals(videoPlayer)) {
         mp.setWakeMode(cordova.getActivity(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
         mp.start();
         mp.seekTo(0);
    }

    mp.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "MediaPlayer.onError(" + what + ", " + extra + ")");

    if (what == 100) { //reached end of stream, it's not really an error
        this.onCompletion(mp);
    }

    if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.stop();
    }

    if (mp != null) {
        mp.setDisplay(null);
        mp.release();
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "MediaPlayer completed");

    try {
        videoPlayer.setDisplay(null);
        videoPlayer.release();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // already released
    }

    try {
        audioPlayer.release();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // already released
    }
}
```

Does someone has an idea why?
Thanks.

**EDIT**

I've noticed that for the videoPlayer I get many warnings of 701\702. Maybe that's related? It seems it keeps buffering the data but never resumes.

Comment: I don't know which api level you are supporting but you could look into https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer which is an alternative to the android mediaplayer but its only available from api level 16.

Comment: yes it free its a library by google

Comment: @Aegis this is no good for me, any other suggestions?

Comment: @DanielY it's no good? Why? ExoPlayer is great. Here's a wrapper to make it easier to use: https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia

Comment: Thanks @Aegis, but I ended up using VLCLib. Thanks.